# Casting NHibernate Lazy loaded objects (Proxy problem) 

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a class Client like that:

```
public class Client{
   public Person Pers { get; set; }
}
```

And I have 2 Person´s child class :

```
public class PersonType1 : Person {...}
public class PersonType2 : Person {...}
```

Now I loaded a client... And I need to get the PersonType1 or PersonType2 attributes ..

I tried that:

```
var _pj = ((PersonType1 ) _client.Pers);
```

But it does not work, because the _client.Pers type is a Proxy (Lazy load true) ...

Is there a way to do that? I have several attributes in each PersonType, so It is not a good idea to create a virtual/override for each attribute (Person->PersonType1) ...

Thanks

Comment: Does this work even with lazy="false"?  If 'Pers' is a proxy type of PersonType1 that cast would work by nature of polymorphism.  My guess is that it isn't returning 'PersonType1', but 'Person'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to eagerly fetch the `Pers` property:

```
var client = session
    .CreateCriteria<Client>()
    .CreateCriteria("Pers", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .Add(Expression.IdEq(1))
    .UniqueResult<Client>();
var pj = (PersonType1)client.Pers;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use NH in the server, and move the objects to the client, you can't use lazy load.
What NH knows (in the server) doesn't help the client, which has neither Session nor knowledge how to fetch the extra data when needed.